# RaphaelJS: Move and scale objects with FreeTransform in limits

Tags: javascript, raphael, transform, collision-detection

I am using the FreeTransform plugin for moving and scaling objects.

I want to limit this moving and scaling to the size of another rect which contains this object. How can I achieve this?

I have provided an example of problem on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwfuj/). (I want the red rect to stay inside the other rect.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The FreeTransform plugin provides the option to set a boundary:

```
    boundary: { x: x-pos, y: y-post, width: i, height: i},
```

see the documentation
https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform/